# How do I get Ocean Sapphire without mining as a profession

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm in need of Ocean Sapphires to get from jewel crafting 520-525. I've bought what's left of them in the Auction House. I do not have mining as a profession and am not sure if it's possible to get them any other way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an alchemist, you can get them through [transmutation of 3 zephyrite and 3 Azshara's Veil](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=80246). Other than that, you are pretty much stuck with buying ore and [prospecting](http://www.wowhead.com/item=52191#prospected-from) it, which you can do yourself as a jewelcrafter.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a tank or healer, you can also get gems through the short-supply reward when there aren't enough of these two roles queuing for dungeons.  You can also get them from lockboxes that can be pickpocketed if you are a rogue.  However, these are random rewards, so it might take a while to get them.

Answer (score 0):

You'll also get some [Ocean Sapphires](http://www.wowhead.com/item=52191) from [Fire Prism's](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=73478), which is how I grinded out my last 5 points to max Jewelcrafting (bearing in mind this isnt really the cheapest way to get your last 5 points anymore, so check AH first). Note this is a once a day crafted item that resets at midnight accordingly.